# Rendering Animation in 3.0 Outputs a Black Silhouette of the Object and is Missing the Background

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image: what I want the render to look like]
This above is a screenshot of the scene in the Viewport Shading - Rnedered Mode.

[image: how the render is outputted]
This screenshot shows how the animation is outputted when rendered. The objects have turned silhouette and the backgorund is missing.

Any ideas on how to fix this will be a life-saver - thanks in advance!

Notes:
Using Eevee at the moment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you upload the blend file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ and post link here? Thanks.

Comment: The pasteall website will not accept my blend file... is there another option for uploading it for you to access?

Comment: @BrickMan1048 https://blend-exchange.com